# Not able to click on java script drop down element using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In our application when I mouse over a menu item, drop down appears, where I want to select an item by clicking on it. The structure of the menu is as follows,

```
 Main Menu
    Admin Sub menu: 
      Manage Channels
      Manage Users
```

In selenium webdriver, I tried to click directly on Manage Channels by giving the xpath, linktext, partial link text. But in options it says unable to locate element. I'm attaching a screen shot for reference

```
 driver.findElement(By.linkText("Manage Channels")).click(); 
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li/a[contains(., \"Manage Channels\")]")).click(); 
 driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Manage Channels"));
```

[image: Menu Screen Shot]

Comment: Can you just show us the HTML of the your Menu items. Also the screenshot is not accessible.Provide us the proper error message that you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you'll have to first move mouse to 'Menu item' drop-down and then move mouse to option which you want to select and then click on option.

For Ruby following is one line code:

```
driver.action.movet_to(el1).movet_to(el2).click.perform
```

I don't know about Java but you can apply above logic. I tried with following Java code, see if it works or modify it wherever required:

```
WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Manage Channels")); 
WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li/a[contains(., \"Manage Channels\")]"))

Actions action = new Actions(driver);    
action.moveToElement(element1).moveToElement(element2).click().build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following methods to hover your mouse on intended menu item:

- el = driver.find_element(:id, "some_id")

  driver.action.move_to(el).perform'
- el = driver.find_element(:id, "some_id")

  driver.action.move_to(el, 100, 100).perform

For more guidelines please refer this link : http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/ActionBuilder.html#move_to-instance_method

Hope this will help you !!!

Cheers...